# Issue with broadcaststream.auto.record=true option in Red5

Tags: windows, red5, flv, live-streaming

I am streaming a live flashsv video (screen share) to Red5 from my Windows PC. In Red5 I have kept broadcaststream.auto.record set to true. Hence, an FLV file is getting recorded capturing the flashsv video stream. 
The issue is the recorded FLV file properties (fps, bitrate, etc) are not right, compared to the live streaming quality.

I would like to know, when using the broadcaststream.auto.record option, what are the fps, bitrate, tbr, tbs, etc Red5 uses to record the stream as an FLV file? Is there any way I can specify my own fps, bitrate for the recording?

I searched a lot online, but couldn't get any detailed explanation of this Red5 recording option.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Mondain Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The video settings for recording will be the same as those on the publishing application, recording does not modify them. In some cases you will need to tweak the recording properties in red5.properties to find the right settings for your implementation.

```
fileconsumer.delayed.write=true
fileconsumer.queue.size=120
```

Increase the queue size if you experience lost frames.